# How do I fix the error for Vue.js in creating a new project 'vue init webpack'

Tags: javascript, vue.js, command-line-interface

The problem is that when I try to start a project on Vue.js (vue init webpack acc001), it gives me a long list of errors after I reach the stage of `npm run dev`, how do I solve this problem?. It occurs in the Node.js command prompt

This is for a new web browser app I want to create. I have tried uninstalling Vue.js, reinstalling Node.js, and then installing Vue.js again but it doesn't work

```
it as { parser: "bab 95% emitting

 WARNING  Compiled with 3 warnings                                                                            8:01:57 PM


  ✘  http://eslint.org/docs/rules/semi          Missing semicolon
  src\App.vue:9:49
  import HelloWorld from './components/HelloWorld'
                                                   ^

  ✘  http://eslint.org/docs/rules/comma-dangle  Missing trailing comma
  src\App.vue:14:15
      HelloWorld
                 ^

  ✘  http://eslint.org/docs/rules/comma-dangle  Missing trailing comma
  src\App.vue:15:4
    }
      ^

  ✘  http://eslint.org/docs/rules/semi          Missing semicolon
  src\App.vue:16:2
  }
    ^


✘ 4 problems (4 errors, 0 warnings)


Errors:
  2  http://eslint.org/docs/rules/comma-dangle
  2  http://eslint.org/docs/rules/semi


  ✘  http://eslint.org/docs/rules/semi          Missing semicolon
  src\main.js:3:22
  import Vue from 'vue'
                        ^

  ✘  http://eslint.org/docs/rules/semi          Missing semicolon
  src\main.js:4:24
  import App from './App'
                          ^

  ✘  http://eslint.org/docs/rules/semi          Missing semicolon
  src\main.js:6:33
  Vue.config.productionTip = false
                                   ^

  ✘  http://eslint.org/docs/rules/comma-dangle  Missing trailing comma
  src\main.js:12:21
    template: '<App/>'
                       ^

  ✘  http://eslint.org/docs/rules/semi          Missing semicolon
  src\main.js:13:3
  })
     ^


✘ 5 problems (5 errors, 0 warnings)


Errors:
  4  http://eslint.org/docs/rules/semi
  1  http://eslint.org/docs/rules/comma-dangle


  ✘  http://eslint.org/docs/rules/space-before-function-paren  Unexpected space before function parentheses
  src\components\HelloWorld.vue:89:7
    data () {
         ^

  ✘  http://eslint.org/docs/rules/comma-dangle                 Missing trailing comma
  src\components\HelloWorld.vue:91:40
        msg: 'Welcome to Your Vue.js App'
                                          ^

  ✘  http://eslint.org/docs/rules/semi                         Missing semicolon
  src\components\HelloWorld.vue:92:6
      }
        ^

  ✘  http://eslint.org/docs/rules/comma-dangle                 Missing trailing comma
  src\components\HelloWorld.vue:93:4
    }
      ^

  ✘  http://eslint.org/docs/rules/semi                         Missing semicolon
  src\components\HelloWorld.vue:94:2
  }
    ^


✘ 5 problems (5 errors, 0 warnings)


Errors:
  2  http://eslint.org/docs/rules/semi
  2  http://eslint.org/docs/rules/comma-dangle
  1  http://eslint.org/docs/rules/space-before-function-paren

You may use special comments to disable some warnings.
Use // eslint-disable-next-line to ignore the next line.
Use /* eslint-disable */ to ignore all warnings in a file.
```

The expected output would be for it to open my default web browser with port 8080 and a Vue.js icon on it but it keeps showing this error message after almost half an hour of waiting

Comment: Why don't you fix the ESLint errors?

Comment: You see errors that are found by ESLint. You either fix them (ESLint fix might fix most of them - like semicolons), or you could modify your ESLint config. Or you might just add ESLint comments/directives in your files to overlook these problems (not advised, as it would take almost as long as fixing them one by one).

Comment: Did you tried hitting localhost:8080 in browser?? Coz these are just lint errors.